# Display certain list when clicking on different links in a view

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I need to display a different list each time I click on different links in my view. Help would be appreciated :)

My controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Teams tm = new Teams();
    Details det = new Details();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new List<Teams>();

        model.Add(new Teams { Name = "Manchester United", NickName = "The Red Devils", HomeGround = "Old Trafford", Founded = 1878 });
        model.Add(new Teams { Name = "Liverpool", NickName = "The reds", HomeGround = "Anfield", Founded = 1870 });

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var title = new List<Details>();

        title.Add(new Details { MajorHonours = 62, PremLeague = 20, FACup = 11, LeagueCup = 4, UEFA = 3 });
        title.Add(new Details { MajorHonours = 60, PremLeague = 18, FACup = 7, LeagueCup = 8, UEFA = 5 });

        return View();
    }
```

My view with the links:

```
@model IEnumerable<Standings.Models.Teams>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Standings";
 }

<h1>List of teams</h1>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
       @Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "About") (@item.NickName, @item.HomeGround, @item.Founded)
    <hr />
</div>
```

}

My model:

```
public class Details
{
    public int MajorHonours { get; set; }
    public int PremLeague { get; set; }
    public int FACup { get; set; }
    public int LeagueCup { get; set; }
    public int UEFA { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a clean View with the name About that the list needs to be displayed on

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect to a view that displays the details for the team you click on?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes! :D

Comment: Your `Teams` - should not be plural :) - should have an `ID` property to uniquely identify it, but assuming the `Name` property is unique, then `@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "About", new { id = @item.Name })`, then the method should be `public ActionResult About(string id)` so you can return a view for the details based on `id`